# Directory traversal only works with URL-encoded "%00" char in the end

Tags: encoding

I found a site, using acunetix, with a POST form which is possible to see plain text files, basically it's a directory traversal vulnerability, but the curious thing is that it only works when I add a "%00" in the end of the query string, something like this:

```
name=../../../../../../../../windows/PFRO.log%00
```

What's it? And why it happens and only works this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%00` is the URL-encoded version of a null byte character. In some applications you can inject a null byte to prematurely terminate a string. An attacker may take advantage of this to cut the end of a string that they can't control.

Here is pseudocode for how the affected code may look like:

```
print(readfile("./" + $name + ".txt"))
```

In this example, any user-supplied value for `$name` would be automatically appended with a `.txt` extension, stopping you from choosing arbitrary file names. To be able to still supply your own path, you can use the `0x00` byte to terminate the string immediately after the payload.

Hence, these paths would be treated equally by the affected system:

```
./../../../../../../../../windows/PFRO.log
./../../../../../../../../windows/PFRO.log%00.txt
```

Null byte injection flaws are common because many higher-level languages are based on C, where a null byte is used to indicate the end of a string. E.g., here is an example of a vulnerable PHP script, taken [from the PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.nullbytes.php):

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file']; // "../../etc/passwd\0"
if (file_exists('/home/wwwrun/'.$file.'.php')) {
    // file_exists will return true as the file /home/wwwrun/../../etc/passwd exists
    include '/home/wwwrun/'.$file.'.php';
    // the file /etc/passwd will be included
}
?>
```

Also see: [Embedding Null Code](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Embedding_Null_Code) on OWASP.